# Issues with the animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, triggers, click

search increase and decrease in width just when the .search_icon is clicked,because in actual moment its changing size when im clicking .search class.And can someone explaing why these code doesnt work with actual jquery library version,thanks. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENqppw

```
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" class="inp"><span class="search_icon"></span></input>  
</div>

$background-color: #2A2E37;
$search-bg-color: #242628;
$icon-color: #00FEDE;
$transition: all 0.5s ease;
.inp{
  width: 240px;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 45px;
  font-size: 40px;
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
}

.search {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: #3a3a3a;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
    margin:50px;
  position:absolute;
 &.open {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
.search_icon {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 3px solid $icon-color;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top:-77px;
  margin-left:20px;
  transition: $transition;
  &:before {
    content: '';
    width: 3px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -2px;
    top: 30px;
    display: block;
    background-color: $icon-color;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: $transition;
  }
  &:after {
    content: '';
    width: 3px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    top: 40px;
    display: block;
    background-color: $icon-color;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: $transition;
  }
  .open & {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    margin-left:95%;
    &:before {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      right: 23px;
      top: 12px;
      height: 29px;
    }
    &:after {
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      right: 23px;
      top: 12px;
      height: 29px;
    }

  }
}

$(function() {
$('.search').on('click', function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('open');
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
  });
```

Comment: Which part is not working exactly? The search icon is expanding and collapsing on click. What is the intended behavior?

Comment: right,its collapsing on all the divs,and spans,but i want it to collapse just on .search_icon class

Comment: i mean on .search_icon class click

Comment: Obviously then you need to bind event to `$('.search_icon')`, not to `$('.search')`

Comment: you can replace `$(this).toggleClass('open');
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');` with `$(this).toggleClass('open clicked');`

Comment: ok thanks but why this code doesnt work with last jquery library?

Comment: using jquery 1.12.4 and it doesnt work

Comment: isn't jQuery Core 3.1.1 last release?

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js

Comment: it doesnt matter :),it doesnt work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lts6ppda/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this instead:

```
$(function() {
    $('.search').on('click', function() { // Expand search on click on it
        $(this).addClass('open clicked');
    });

    $('.search_icon').on('click', function(e) { // Collapse search on click on search icon
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).closest('.search').removeClass('open clicked');
    });
});
```

Comment: well it works on js fiddle now,but not for me yet :/

Comment: Do you have jquery included?

Comment: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: You need to add jquery in the external resources on the left. Also you have to change the css to scss from the settings icon on the top right in the pane where you add the styles. Here is an updated [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lts6ppda/28/) with these changes

Comment: ok it will work on jsfiddle,but how will it work on my site,becauase i dont understand :/